# Duplicity does not run via anacron in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, duplicity, anacron

Since the implementation of the lockfile option I cannot run duplicity via anacron (https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1320641). Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how duplicity works, but I guess you could check and kill running duplicity processes, and remove the lockfile. This may be dangerous, but any circumvention of the lockfile is potentially dangerous, really.

Comment: It's better to report essential information in the question rather than putting a link. ;) BTW, your error message says *Another instance is already running with this archive directory*. Are you really sure Duplicity is not already running when the new backup process starts?

Comment: Yes i am absolutely sure that another instance is not running at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doing

> rm -rf ~/.cache/deja-dup/*
>
> rm -rf ~/.cache/duplicity/*

seems to fix the problem.

Source https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1318833

Answer (score 1):

The previous version does not have that bug. So why not downgrade?
For example with `sudo apt-get install duplicity=0.6.21-0ubuntu4.1`.

> If I remove the .cache/duplicity/ before anacron runs the script the script also runs successfully.

This may be due to the interruption of duplicity by a signal during shutdown. Try shutdown the OS during manual backup and run it again manually to check if that error occurs.
[this](https://github.com/originalmind/duplicity-backup) fork on github handles interrupt signals as follows

```
# The lock succeeded. Create a signal handler to remove the lock file when the process terminates.  
trap 'EXITCODE=$?; echo "Removing lock. Exit code: ${EXITCODE}" >>${LOGFILE}; rm -f "${LOCKFILE}"' 0
```

you may try this.